# only last row of arraylist being saved in JSON object

Tags: java, php, android, json, arraylist

I have an arraylist containing multiple rows of data I wish to pass from android to a PHP server where it is displayed. I placed the arraylist contents in a JSON object which I pass on to a name-value-pair list before parsing.

My problem is when i output the value of the recieved JSON. It only displays the last of records.

PHP CODE:

```
<?php


if($_POST)
{
echo "Smething was sent";

$JSON_Entry = $_POST["Entry"];

$obj = json_decode($JSON_Entry);

$i = 0;

print_r($obj);
}

?>
```

JAVA CODE:

```
        ArrayList<SalesReciepts> entryList = db.getSalesRecords();

        List<NameValuePair> postVars = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();



        for (int i = 0; i < entryList.size(); i++) {

            try {
                JSONentry.put("id", String.valueOf(entryList.get(i).getEntryId()));
                JSONentry.put("invoice",String.valueOf(entryList.get(i).getInvoice_id()));
                JSONentry.put("product", String.valueOf(entryList.get(i).getProduct()));
                JSONentry.put("qty", String.valueOf(entryList.get(i).getQty()));
                JSONentry.put("total", String.valueOf(entryList.get(i).getTotal()));
            }
            catch(JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }



        JSONObject sent = new JSONObject();


        try {
            sent.put("records", String.valueOf(JSONentry));
        }
        catch(JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        postVars.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Entry", String.valueOf(sent)));


        //Declare and Initialize Http Clients and Http Posts
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(POST_PRODUCTS);

        //Format it to be sent
        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postVars));

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /* Send request and Get the Response Back */
        try {

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());


            Log.e("response:", responseBody );

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            Log.v("MAD", "Error sending... ");


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            Log.v("MAD", "Error sending... ");


        }
```

OUTPUT:

```
  Smething was sent{"records":"{\"total\":\"1398.0\",\"product\":\"Carlsberg\",\"id\":\"0\",\"qty\":\"2\",\"invoice\":\"2.4082015083321E13\"}"}
```

The output displays the last of 3 rows/records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a new `JSONentry` for each loop iteration, then add it to your `JSONArray`.

Change your code like that:

```
            ArrayList<SalesReciepts> entryList = db.getSalesRecords();

            List<NameValuePair> postVars = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            JSONArray recordsJsonArray = = new JSONArray();


            for (int i = 0; i < entryList.size(); i++) {

                try {
                    JSONObject JSONentry = new JSONObject(); // here you create a new JSONObject

                    JSONentry.put("id", String.valueOf(entryList.get(i).getEntryId()));
                    JSONentry.put("invoice",String.valueOf(entryList.get(i).getInvoice_id()));
                    JSONentry.put("product", String.valueOf(entryList.get(i).getProduct()));
                    JSONentry.put("qty", String.valueOf(entryList.get(i).getQty()));
                    JSONentry.put("total", String.valueOf(entryList.get(i).getTotal()));

                    recordsJsonArray.put(JSONentry); // here you add the item to your array
                }
                catch(JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            JSONObject sent = new JSONObject();

            try {
                sent.put("records", String.valueOf(recordsJsonArray));
            }
            catch(JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            postVars.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Entry", String.valueOf(sent)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new JSONentry after every loop. Right now you only are overriding the last set value over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Without being a Java specialist, but I would say you need to 
change this line and the following ones 
 JSONentry.put("id", String.valueOf(entryList.get(i).getEntryId()));
with something like "id[]" 
but again - I am not a JAVA expert, but it strongly looks like you are overriding the same values over and over and therefore only the last is caught in PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSONEntry is a JSONObject. You need to make a JSONArray where you will put your different JSONEntry